# Can we simultaneously use the particles 地 and 得 with a single verb, e.g. 他高兴地跳得高?

Tags: grammar, particles

I'm sure 他高兴地跳着 and 他跳得高 are fine, but I'm not sure if we can combine them, like in:

> 他高兴**地**跳**得**高。
> He happily jumped high.

Here we have the grammar structure:

> Subject + adv. + 地 + verb + 得 + complement.

**Question**: Can we simultaneously use the particles 地 and 得 with a single verb?

I asked [Assistant](https://poe.com/s/VKXIHj96xlcU9fxmorsr), and it says it's okay, but I'm not convinced the AI is correct here.  I [asked further](https://poe.com/s/t2us1NWsPkmzekzwDVfw), and it gave me other examples like 他认真地学得快 and 她小心地开得快, and so on.  I Googled [`"他高兴地跳得高"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E4%BB%96%E9%AB%98%E5%85%B4%E5%9C%B0%E8%B7%B3%E5%BE%97%E9%AB%98%22), and it gave 高兴地跳了起来, which doesn't use both 地 and 得.

Comment: As far as I learnt, there are no restrictions about the use of 地 and 得 at the same sentence. The structure only focused on what must come after the 地 and 得, but never explained if they can be used together. So it supposed to be fine to use both in the same sentence, but just a bit strange for the audience (listener or reader).

Comment: You'd better not use 地 and 得 in one sentence.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to use both in the same sentence. Googling whole prefabricated sentences will probably give you no results, but if you just search  "地跳得" (or any other verbs), you will find such constructions as:

如何自然地跳得更好？
我慌不择路地跑得更快了。

It's not rare, but also not very frequent.

Answer (score 5):

Native speakers might find it somewhat more natural to say "he was so happy that he jumped" i.e. 高兴得跳了起来 rather than  "he jumped happily" 高兴地跳了起来. The adverbial particle 地 is not commonly used compared to adverbs in English. You would encounter it more often in translated and/or scholastic texts where the grammar is more Europeanized. Granted, this is only applicable in a written context.

On the other hand one cannot ordinarily use single-syllabic content words like 高 in the predicate.

1. *他高兴得跳得高。 Instead,
2. 他高兴地跳得很高/老高/三尺高/高高的。

A simple tip for learners is that one may precede single syllables with the intensifier "很" whenever possible. It's ok to say 小王很高 even if you consider 小王 merely a bit tall. The intensifier is used for the sole purpose of avoiding saying *小王高 and carries little actual meaning.

Comment: 小王很高，小王比较高，小王高一点儿，小王并不高，etc.

Answer (score 2):

他高兴地跳得高。It does not seem correct.

You can say, 他高兴地跳了起来。跳得很高。

In Chinese, there are three "DE", 的，地，得. Sometimes we read them as "DI", which is OK.

The word 的 is used to modify nouns. So it is for adjectives.

The words 地 and 得 are both to modify verbs. So they are both for adverbs. I think this is the reason they do not stay together. For example, we do NOT say,

(1a) 她伤心地哭得很厉害。

But you can split this sentence into two sentences.

(1b) 她伤心地哭了。哭得很厉害。

Or you can use 着 instead of 得。

他高兴地跳着脚。跳得很高。

Or,

他高兴地跳着舞，唱着歌。

Comment: “we do NOT say, (1a) 她伤心地哭得很厉害。”。。。

But it's possible to find many, many examples of Chinese people using just this structure. So I would say it's maybe not perfect grammar, but it still seems quite colloquial. Like (examples found on the net):
- ... 转而感动地哭得稀里哗啦...
- 婴儿挥手蹬脚地哭得厉害
And many more.

Answer (score 2):

It's grammatically correct. However because 的地得 have the same pronunciation in Mandarin, in practical usage, there is always a priori assumption of their placement. An uncommon usage will only cause confusion since people will always attempt to understand it using their own assumption of particles.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

她高兴的一蹦三尺高。

I remember you asked once  about a book using 的 instead of 地。

Comment: 的 here should be either 地 or 得, with slightly different nuances, but that aside, I find this phrasing much more natural than alternatives given by other answers such as 他高兴地跳得很高.

Answer (score 0):

Two interpretations of "得":

- "跳**得**高" - "**Able to** jump up high". Note that this is a complete/independent phrase, which does not require a modifier.
- "**跳得**高高的" - "**Jumped** very high". Note that "very high" indicates the extent of the "jump", and the phrase can be modified by the adverb "高兴地" - "高兴地跳得高高的".